# Is it possible to use authentication with an ImageEx control to bind to a url that requires authentication

Tags: windows-community-toolkit

I am successfully using an ImageEx control to render images in a ListView with the code:

```
<controls:ImageEx 
                    IsCacheEnabled="True" Source="{Binding thumbnail}"
                    PlaceholderSource="/Assets/movie.png"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                    Stretch="Fill" />
```

where thumbnail is the url of the image. Is it possible to pass username/password to access the url that requires authentication?

Comment: Are you asking if you can set the `Source` to something like `http://username:password@example.com/`? If so, that should be fine.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work - in my project it causes an error - system.runtime.interopservices.comexception (0x800c000e): a security problem occurred

Comment: Does it work with a regular Image control?

Comment: It doesn't work with a regular image control. Without the username and password a authentication dialog comes up and then it works if entered correctly, but with the username and password in the URL it just fails to load the image, without throwing an error.

Comment: Look like an improvement could be made. Can you log an issue on [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/new)?